# Ubuntu Phone--is there one that works in the Americas?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I see that the Ubuntu Phone is now available, but I only see it on Ubuntu's site as for sale in Europe.  Does anyone know if there is an Ubuntu phone available for use in the Americas, specifically the US?  Does anyone know if the Ubuntu phones designed for Europe would work on US providers/work off US towers?  If it is possible to get an Ubuntu phone for use in the US right now, I would appreciate directions as to where to get it and what providers support it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: I disagree in this case. Given that the answer is "there aren't any", this no longer a subjective shopping recommendation and more an objective statement of fact. The question is asked so often everywhere it would be nice to have a place to link this FAQ, and this seems like a good venue.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Ubuntu Phone for the US yet.  The BQ phone released in Europe will only be able to use 2G in the US, I believe.  So it might technically work, but not in a way you would find usable.

Cristian Parrino from Canonical [said](https://svij.org/blog/2015/02/11/cristian-parrino-from-canonical-about-the-release-of-ubuntu-phone-and-future-plans/) an announcement for the US market would happen before August.

Comment: Thank you, and I will keep an eye out for the announcement for the US market.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on AT&T and located in Maryland. I purchased a BQ Ubuntu Edition off of Amazon from a private seller. I can confirm that 2g and 3G work perfectly.